# Convergence/Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac {1+\cos(n)}3 \right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to see if this series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\limits \left(\frac {1+\cos(n)}3 \right)^n$ either converges or diverges.  I was thinking that because the inside terms are going to fluctuate between $(0,\frac 23)$, the inside is never negative, so it's going to diverge because a sum of positive numbers raised to a power are strictly increasing?  Is my logic correct here and/or if there is a theorem that strengthens my argument, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{1+\cos(n)}3 \right|^n
\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac23\right)^n<\infty,
$$
hence the series converges absolutely, hence converges.

Comment: This isn't a hint

Comment: @Goobys Too detailed? But, as we may deduce fro the question, OP will have enough work with the remaining details.

Comment: What I was referring to was the fact that you said "**Hint**", yet still gave the entirety of the solution in your answer. A hint is not supposed to give the whole answer.

Answer (score 1):

The series converges. As you noted $1 + \cos(n) \leq 2$ so we have:

$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+\cos(n)}{3} \leq \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} (2/3)^n = 2$  by the geometric series forumla.